# Ranger hdfs plugin not found in UI and not able to see audit logs

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, audit

Currently I am working with HDP 2.3 and Ranger 0.5. I want to install hdfs plugin on the namenode so that I can see the audit logs in Ranger UI. I have selected audit store as 'db'. I also see this message:"Ranger Plugin for hadoop has been enabled. Please restart hadoop to ensure that changes are effective." But, I am not able to see any plugin in audits->plugins. I am not able to see any logs also in the UI. What can be the issue?